# MaskedTextbox unable to insert NULL date into SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have `maskedtextbox` which inserts date into SQL `data type` date. IN SQL it has NULLs allowed but if I try to insert this maskedtextbox empty. It gives an error that it is unable to convert symbols into Date data type. This maskedtextbox is like **.**.*_*_ (DD.MM.YYYY)

My `Parameter` for INSERT INTO `SqlCommand` is this:

```
   prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("zodjdate", maskedTextBox2.Text);
```

How should I change it to make it insert NULLs?

Thanks in advance.
M.S.

Comment: Empty string is different to null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var value = (object) DBNull.Value;
DateTime parsedDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(maskedTextBox2.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", null, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
{
    value = parsedDate;
}
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("zodjdate", value);
```

Comment: This gave me this error: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between: System.DBNUll and string. Thanks for helping but what should I do with this?

Comment: Right, you should cast `DBNull.Value` to `object`.  Both sides of the `:` can be converted to `object`.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried that but it still gaves me the same error message that : t it is unable to convert symbols into Date data type. Don't you know where the error might be?

Comment: You can avoid SQL conversion errors by parsing the string client side.  I've updated the answer again :)

Comment: I have also tried this:prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("zodjdate", maskedTextBox2.Text == string.Empty ? "0" : maskedTextBox2.Text); But it keeps giving me the same error with converting symbols.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but it says that "DateTimeStyles" does not exists in current context. I'm quiet begginer in c# and SQL so I don't want to waste your time. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Include `using System.Globalization;` at the top of your `.cs` file.  Visual Studio should give you a shortcut link to do that for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33440/discussion-between-marek-sip-and-andomar)